# Why don't forms receive WM_NOTIFY messages for children of a TFrame?

Tags: delphi, winapi, tframe, window-messages

The WM_NOTIFY message is often used for in-place "tool tips" (message balloon) and other control notifications, but if I place a control on a TFrame, then WM_NOTIFY messages never occur for those controls. Why aren't those messages sent to my form anymore, and what can I do about it?

Comment: I cannot duplicate your issue. ToolTip window style=0, TToolInfo.uFlags:=TTF_IDISHWND or TTF_SUBCLASS, Info.hwnd:=Form.Handle, Info.uId:=Control.Handle, and the form itself receives WM_NOTIFY for TTN_SHOW and TTN_POP for instance, not the frame or anything else (for windowed controls of course). I think you've got something wrong setting the ToolTip itself.

Answer (score 7):

`WM_NOTIFY` is sent to the parent window of a control.  That means the `TFrame`, not its own parent `TForm` (or another parent), will receive the message for its direct child controls.

You should not be handling `WM_NOTIFY` directly.  Subclass the child control itself, such as by assigning a new `WindowProc` handler to it, and then handle the `CN_NOTIFY` message instead.  The VCL will receive the original `WM_NOTIFY` message and automatically forward it as a `CN_NOTIFY` message to the particular control that it belongs to.

The same applies to `WM_COMMAND` (forwarded as `CN_COMMAND`) and many other forwarded system messages.  The Controls.pas unit defines all of the available `CN_...` messages that are defined for forwarded system messages.

Comment: This is a generalized answer which does not apply to this specific question. ToolTip controls, if set up correctly, interface with their *owner* window. Which makes sense because it is the ToolTip control that notifies, not individual child controls.

Comment: This may be a generalized answer, but Alfa000 asked a generalized question. Without knowing the specific details of how s/he is actually creating and showing the tooltips, it is very possible that the `TForm` is NOT the owning window for the tooltips, which would explain why the `TForm` is not receiving `WM_NOTIFY` messages for controls that are placed on a `TFrame`.  My guess is that s/he is actually using `Control.Handle` or `Control.Parent.Handle` instead (the latter would allow `WM_NOTIFY` to be sent to the `TForm` window for controls placed on the `TForm` itself).

Comment: I have no objection to your comment, but the answer still does not apply. It says *"WM_NOTIFY is sent to the parent window of a control"*, a ToolTip control's window has no parent, it is a popup window.

Comment: Alfa000 also mentioned control notifications, not just tooltips.  My comments definately apply to control notifications.

Comment: Ah, in fact he didn't. I didn't re-read the question after Rob modified it, "other controls" are his interpretation. Also the modified title asks now what you've answered... Ok then, sorry for the trouble :). Let's see if Alfa have got anything to say..

Comment: @Sertac, I added the bit about "other controls" because the "for example" link that Alfa provided had *nothing* to do with tool-tip notifications; it was a link giving us an example of what tool tips *are*, which I think was pointless. Alfa never *said* the notify messages that he or she isn't getting were for tool tips; all the question said is that notify messages are used for tool tips, which is true, but irrelevant for anyone who already knows what tool tips are. Alfa *did* talk about placing controls on a frame, and that's not something you can do with a tool tip.

Comment: @Rob - Ok. Obviously it was possible to understand it both ways. I read the question as *"WM_NOTIFY message is often used for in-place tooltips .."* (discard example) *"But if i place control to a TFrame, .."*. I'm gonna downvote the question.

Comment: Thank you guys for your interest. I should by more specific. My English is really poor and funny, but i try this.

Pleas forget the tooltip for now.

For example i use only single TForm and TAnyWinControl. TAnyWinControl uses WM_NOTIFY message for any purpose. If component structure is created like this: "TForm->TAnyWinControl" everything works well. But if components are created like this: "TForm->TFrame->TAnyWinControl" then metod TAnyWinControl.WmNotify is never called! If i put the breakpoit to this metod, then program never stop here.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, Alfa. The control isn't supposed to send wm_Notify messages to itself. It's supposed to send them to its parent. That's how wm_Notify works. Furthermore, even if it *does* sent itself those messages, I don't see how a control's parent would affect that. Can you please give a specific example of a standard Delphi control that behaves the way you describe? (If not a standard Delphi control, then at least one that is commonly available, so we can see it ourselves.)

Comment: I using this demo [link](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/asg76.asp). I study code of TAdvStringGrid. TAdvStringGrid use WMNotify metod for fill Tooltip Window content. But if i put TAdvStringGrid to TFrame, then WmNotify is never executed.

Comment: @Alfa, `TAdvStringGrid` descends from `TStringGrid`, as such it shouldn't cause *any* WM_NOTIFY to be sent *anywhwere*. What causes the notifications to be sent should be the ToolTip control, for a possible cause to your problem read Remy's first comment to this answer.   > *"Pleas forget the tooltip for now"* > Then your question is already answered. Please ask another one if you have another question.